# How to schedule a task dynamically in spring java

Tags: java, spring

I want to schedule a task dynamiclly for example i have task A, B, C.
I want to execute task 'A' at 9 am,  task 'B' at 12.30 pm and task 'C' at 7 pm.
But i dont want to repeat the task on same time every day.
I want to set task schedule dynamiclly .
I have Googled a lot and i found only static task scheduling procedure.
In spring java i got only fixed and
 cron expression like this  @Scheduled(cron = "0 15 10 15 * ?")   which is totally static , for cron expression you can just run a task on a fixed time of a day.
So please help me.

Comment: What would be your dynamic strategy?

Comment: @pablosaraiva, Suppose i want to set a task on 08 November 10 pm, and it will execute only on that time , it won't repeat.
And i can set task whenever i want (for example there are some program on my website and user can set any time whenever he wants to watch that program and server will notify the user on that specific time.

Comment: You should take a look to [official document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#scheduling). Specially `TaskScheduler` that can trigger a task at a specified time.

Answer (score 9):

I think you're looking for this (from [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#scheduling)):

> ### The Spring TaskScheduler Abstraction
>
> In addition to the `TaskExecutor` abstraction, Spring 3.0 introduced a
>   `TaskScheduler` with a variety of methods for scheduling tasks to run
>   at some point in the future. The following listing shows the
>   `TaskScheduler` interface definition:
>
> ```
> public interface TaskScheduler {
>
>     ScheduledFuture schedule(Runnable task, Trigger trigger);
>
>     ScheduledFuture schedule(Runnable task, Instant startTime);
>
>     ScheduledFuture schedule(Runnable task, Date startTime);
>
>     ScheduledFuture scheduleAtFixedRate(Runnable task, Instant startTime, Duration period);
>
>     ScheduledFuture scheduleAtFixedRate(Runnable task, Date startTime, long period);
>
>     ScheduledFuture scheduleAtFixedRate(Runnable task, Duration period);
>
>     ScheduledFuture scheduleAtFixedRate(Runnable task, long period);
>
>     ScheduledFuture scheduleWithFixedDelay(Runnable task, Instant startTime, Duration delay);
>
>     ScheduledFuture scheduleWithFixedDelay(Runnable task, Date startTime, long delay);
>
>     ScheduledFuture scheduleWithFixedDelay(Runnable task, Duration delay);
>
>     ScheduledFuture scheduleWithFixedDelay(Runnable task, long delay);
> }
> ```

`TaskScheduler` can schedule a task at a specifed `Date` or `Instant`:

```
ScheduledFuture schedule(Runnable task, Instant startTime);

ScheduledFuture schedule(Runnable task, Date startTime);
```

So you should be able to do:

```
scheduler.schedule(task, new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format("2018-11-07 17:46:00"));
```

Comment: But, using TaskScheduler how dynamic time scheduling would happen? like I have 100 tasks between 2 hours and their scheduling is different. How can I reschedule the task based on their time?